# View not showing properly in android layout

Tags: java, android, layout, customdialog

I am designing custom dialogue in android, For this purpose I designed xml file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="@color/item_bg_color"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_text"
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="You are not authorized to use this application." 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/custom_button_ok" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_dialog_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custom_dialog_text"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Problem :**

I want to show button at end (Right) of TextView, And textview's text should be in more than one line(if more characters have to show). But when I am using this layout, button is not appearing anywhere.

I used LinearLayout and TableLayout also and in both cases, button is appearing with a little part. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to tell the button to be align to the right, take all the space it needs, then give the rest of the space to the TextView. You do this by specifying `android:layout_layout_alignParentRight="true"` for the button and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/custom_button_ok"` for the TextView. Mind the order!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="@color/item_bg_color" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button android:id="@+id/custom_button_ok" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Ok" 
   android:layout_layout_alignParentRight="true" />

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_text"
   android:textColor="#000000" 
   android:textSize="14dip"
   android:typeface="serif"
   android:singleLine="false"
   android:text="You are not authorized to use this application." 
   android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/custom_button_ok"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For  Button add the attributes android:layout_alignParentRight,android:layout_below,they help you

Answer (score 0):

try doin this..

```
<TextView android:layout_width="100dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_text"
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="You are not authorized to use this application." 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

layout_belw and  layout_rightof properties are set to same Id in text view.Just use layout_below.Also u can set gravity of button to bottom

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1.0">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.85">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="14dip"
            android:typeface="serif" android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="You are not authorized to use zdsaddsad this application."
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.15">
        <Button android:id="@+id/custom_button_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ok" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer is working for me, but did you see depth of Layouts? Is this good design for only two view.

Comment: if you used weight sum concept it is best never your design to break any screen so that i have used that. you can directly given textview and button to wight sum concept

Comment: Sure I will upvote your answer, but can you share some links or information about those things which you added in comment. And previously why I didn't upvote, you can understand by my first comment.